# Node.js application not rendering mongoDB collection after model.find()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm experiencing an issue in my node application with accessing the contents of a mongoDB collection via mongoose.

this problem only ever happens the very first time my application makes a call to the database collection. what should occur when the user presses the submit button, is that the contents of the collection should be added dynamically to the DOM. However, this does not occur. but when I check the collection via the command line interface, the user submitted data is there, and then when I press the refresh button on the browser (which hits the same route the user was redirected to upon initially submitting the form) the data renders to the page like it should have the first time.

When I noticed this, i tried starting from scratch. I dropped my database, restarted my server, but this time, I used robo3t to create the db and the collection before I started my app and filled out the form data, and viola, when I submit my data and hit save, the information gets saved to the collection AND rendered the the page successfully the first time.

So i went and looked at the different Model methods provided by mongoose and thought maybe I just needed to add a function call to initialize the collection sometime before calling Model.find() but everything i'm looking at tells me that the collection is already (obviously) initialized when you call mongoose.model()

so i'm a little confused about what to do in order to make sure my data gets rendered to the webpage the first time the user submits information, rather than after refreshing.....i've been careful about awaiting all the async functionality but maybe I missed something?

the repo is here in the unlikely case someone wants to clone this and try to recreate the situation. Let me know if there is more information I can provide

https://github.com/Funkh0user/TripCheq-Travel-Assistant

Thank you.

Comment: Hi there! Can you please post or provide a link to the form code and the express route handler that handles the request

Comment: yeah its all in the github repo. the application javascript is in /src/client/index.js and the server javascript is in src/server/index.js

the two app.GET routes that are relevent are /setData and /userData. i can confirm that the data is where it should be (mongoDB collection) every time, but, most of the time (though not every time) i have to hit the save button twice or hit save once and refresh the page before I see the elements in the dom.
(I probably don't even deserve help on this, i can't imagine anyone else actually looking through all that code and not wanting to choke me after.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it. I needed to rearrange some things such that the block of code responsible for doing some computations and then sending the result back to the application was in the callback for model.find()

Thanks!